# How to generate the same result when adding two Strings 'A+B' == 'B+A'

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I am making a Flutter chat app. In my app, when one creates an account, they will have a string value of username and userId along with other attributes.

The problem I am having is that, when user 'A' send a message to user 'B', it creates a channel called 'A_B', which I did by `A.username + B.username`, but how do I make sure that, when user 'B' sends message to user 'A', it will create the same channel name and not 'B_A'?

Comment: You do a comparison between the two and consistently use lesser + greater.

Comment: wow, I don't know why I did not think of that. thank you so much @shawnt00

Comment: @shawnt00 make that an answer. Alternatives: add ascii-numbers of all chars. Are usernames unique? Otherwise I'd recommend giving them unique IDs or UUIDs.

Comment: username are not unique, but I do have userId that is UUID, but is is too long to put as a channel name

Comment: PS, come to think about it, I might as well make username unique, otherwise this will be tricky for users with the same username

Comment: If you need unique channel names, you probably will need some other restrictions on the usernames so that users "A_B" and "C" don't create the same channel name as users "A" and "B_C".

Comment: good point @jamesdlin, I will consider that.

Answer (score 3):

In math this would be called a canonical form. Establish a convention that your channel name is always represented by the usernames in alphabetical order. Something like this:

```
if A < B
    channel = A + B
else
    channel = B + A
```

And yes, you want to combine them with a character(s) that aren't valid in the usernames to avoid ambiguity with names like "AB" and "C" vs "A" and "BC".